# One QuickSort algorithm, many ways to choose a pivot and as many problems with it

Tags: java, random, pivot, quicksort, median

I got a task to implement a QuickSort algorithm on an ArrayList which can use as a pivot:

1. Last item of an ArrayList.
2. Random item of an ArrayList.
3. Median value of the first one, the last one and the middle value of the ArrayList.

The problem is that only the first way works 100% properly and the rest is making some weird mistakes and I can not find the mistake. Maybe one of you will be able to do it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sortowanie {

    ArrayList<Integer> data;

    public Sortowanie(String File) {
        data=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
            String wiersz = null;
            while((wiersz = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String [] liczby = wiersz.split(",");
                wiersz.trim();
                for(int i=0; i<liczby.length; i++) {
                    int liczba= Integer.parseInt(liczby[i]);
                    data.add(liczba);
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void quicksort( int x, int y, int v) {

        int i,j,temp;

        i=x;
        j=y;
        int pivot=0;
        switch(v) {
        case 0: {
            pivot = y;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            Random r=new Random();
            pivot = (r.nextInt(y-x+1))+x;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            int naj=x;
            if(data.get((x+y)/2)>data.get(naj)) naj=((x+y)/2);
            if(data.get(y)>data.get(naj)) naj=y;
            pivot=naj;
            break;
            }
        }

        do {
            while (data.get(i)<data.get(pivot))
                i++;
            while (data.get(pivot)<data.get(j))
                j--;
            if (i<=j) {
                temp=data.get(i);
                data.set( i, data.get(j));
                data.set(j, temp);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        } while (i<=j); 

        if (x<j) {
            quicksort(x,j, v);
            //  System.out.println("while(x<j)");
        }
        if (i<y) {
            quicksort(i,y, v);
            //System.out.println("while(i<y)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more about the 'weird mistakes'? Wrong Indices? multiple occurence of a value? What's exactly the issue?

Comment: Mostly numbers are sorted in a correct way but then suddenly there is a line of numbers which should be in a other place (but whats important also this numbers are sorted correctly). For example there is a line of numbers: 88,     88,     89,     91,     62,     62,     63,     63,     63,     64,     64,     65,     66,     66 and so far.

Answer (score 0):

There were several small mistakes that you did mostly related to using the index where you should have used the value of the array at that index and vice versa.

First of all the pivot is not calculated correctly in any of the cases. In the first case instead of `pivot = y` you should be looking for the value at `y`: `pivot = data.get(y)`. Similarly in the second case you generate a random number that is in the range of the list's size, but the picot should be equal to the value at that index:

```
int randomInt = (r.nextInt(y - x + 1)) + x;
pivot = data.get(randomInt);
```

In the third case instead of `pivot = naj` it should be `pivot = data.get(naj)`. Finally in the body of the first and second `while` `data.get(pivot)` was used instead of the `pivot`. And here is how the complete code looks:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Sortowanie {

    public ArrayList<Integer> data;

    public Sortowanie(String File) {
        data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
            String wiersz = null;
            while ((wiersz = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] liczby = wiersz.split(",");
                wiersz.trim();
                for (int i = 0; i < liczby.length; i++) {
                    int liczba = Integer.parseInt(liczby[i]);
                    data.add(liczba);
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void quicksort(int x, int y, int v) {
        int i, j, temp;
        i = x;
        j = y;
        int pivot = 0;
        switch (v) {
            case 0: {
                pivot = data.get(y);
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                Random r = new Random();
                int randomInt = (r.nextInt(y - x + 1)) + x;
                pivot = data.get(randomInt);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                int naj = x;
                if (data.get((x + y) / 2) > data.get(naj)) naj = ((x + y) / 2);
                if (data.get(y) > data.get(naj)) naj = y;
                pivot = data.get(naj);
                break;
            }
        }

        do {
            while (data.get(i) < pivot)
                i++;
            while (pivot < data.get(j))
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                temp = data.get(i);
                data.set(i, data.get(j));
                data.set(j, temp);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        } while (i <= j);

        if (x < j) {
            quicksort(x, j, v);
            //  System.out.println("while(x<j)");
        }
        if (i < y) {
            quicksort(i, y, v);
            //System.out.println("while(i<y)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was checking code many times and haven't noticed this obvious mistake ;)